# Different bugs in LinkedHashMap - java8.1

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

If I access the keys of a `LinkedHashMap<Vector, Vector<Integer>>` inside its class it is extracted correctly, but if I create an instance of its class and call a class method that displays the LinkedHashMap, I find some of the fields in the keys that are instances of Vector are missing.

```
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
public class TestLinkedHashMap 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.setSample();      
        System.out.println("The sample printed in main function is : \n" + t.getSample());
        return;
    }
}

class Test
{
    LinkedHashMap<Vector, Vector<Integer>> sample;

    public Test()
    {
        sample = 
            new LinkedHashMap<Vector, Vector<Integer>>();
    }

    public LinkedHashMap<Vector, Vector<Integer>> getSample()
    {
        return sample;
    }

    public void setSample()
    {
        Vector record1 = new Vector();
        record1.add(new String("Apple"));
        record1.add(new String("Orange"));
        record1.add(new String("Grapes"));
        record1.add(new String("Lime"));
        Vector<Integer> v1 = new Vector<Integer>();
        v1.add(new Integer(0));
        v1.add(new Integer(8));
        v1.add(new Integer(28));
        System.out.println("sample = " + sample);
        sample.put(new Vector(record1), v1);
        Vector record2 = new Vector();
        record2.add(new String("Pineapple"));
        record2.add(new String("Pear"));
        record2.add(new String("Mango"));
        Vector<Integer> v2 = new Vector<Integer>();
        v2.add(new Integer(0));
        v2.add(new Integer(18));
        sample.put(new Vector(record2), v2);
        System.out.println("The sample printed inside the class is : \n" + sample);
    }
```

Above code works fine, but in the application I am developing, I am getting different outputs for the sample. I have included the output of my application below. My application is using LinkedHashMap in similar manner as above.

Output is different in real application

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to use something mutable as key. You are messing up the hashes in the hashmap. The documentation explicitly warned you not to use something mutable as the key.

Comment: I think you maybe right, then only solution would be to convert the Vector to string and store it as a key.

Comment: Random thought: Maybe OP could just use the toString output of the Vector objects as keys, because I think those don't ever change.

Comment: Side note: if you don't need the thread-safety of `Vector`, `ArrayList` is preferred (says the javadoc of `Vector`).

Answer (score 1):

Of course `this.sample` is `null`. You never set it to a value. In the constructor, you’re creating a new `LinkedHashMap<Vector, Vector<Integer>>` , but not actually assigning it to the class member variable `sample`, instead you’re just creating a local variable (local to the constructor) called `sample`.

Remove the `LinkedHashMap<Vector, Vector<Integer>>` before `sample` in the constructor and that will initialize the class member variable `sample` as expected.

Comment: deleted the redeclaring of sample